# I comment on answer why NAA and flagged but my flag is declined

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer

Regarding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690271/com-avaje-ebean-model-cannot-be-resolved-play-framework-2-6/53689945#53689945), I flag NAA and comment on that post.

[image: For > 10k]

> How your answer is different from above answer

The post is deleted, but my flag is declined. Why?

Comment: That's not NAA, that's why the flag was declined. Answer which is copy of other answer is still an answer.

Comment: Copy from another answer is still answer @ShadowWizard ?

Comment: Yup. Why not? It's not VLQ either, such answers should just be downvoted and voted to delete, if that fails, you can raise custom flag, explaining why it should be deleted.

Comment: May you see; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376147/remove-ion-item-divider/49660932#49660932 copy from answer and deleted by mod.

Comment: Yes, saw it, what about it? It is an answer, even correct answer, just happens to be a copy of other answer. Like before, NAA flag is wrong.

Comment: So copy another answer and paste as new answer given with new link is ok ?

Comment: Of course it's not OK and it should be deleted, just not flagged as NAA. Custom flag is also better since mod can check the user's history, and if same user doing this several times, the mod will suspend them. (While with just NAA flag, mod won't bother to check history.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. I try to understand how SO work :D

Comment: Users with reputation ≥ 10k (more precisely, the moderator-tools privilege; 2k on beta sites) can vote to delete questions that have been closed/put on hold or marked as duplicate for 48 hours. It takes three votes to delete; more if the question is popular, but ten votes at most.  Unable to cast delete flag.